# Какой код надо дописать для этой игры?

Tags: python, android, разработка-игр, pygame, обновление

Как сделать таймер(Изначальное время 5 секунд, когда он дойдёт до нуля счёт сбрасывается, кроме рекорда, а при нажатии на правильную кнопку время восстанавливается), рандом чисел(При нажатии на правильную кнопку время восстанавливается и добавляет 1 очко к счету а также к рекорду, если он побит. А при неправильной счёт сбрасывается) рекорд для игры(Когда счет больше рекорда то он(рекорд) перезаписывается и сохраняется после выхода из игры) ссылка на сайт(в углу будет значок, если на него нажать то откроется сайт) и как сделать эту игру доступным для android(.apk) на питон?
Сам код игры:

```
from tkinter import *
import random as rn
root = Tk()
root.title('Мой первый графический интерфейс')
root.geometry('720x1280')

clicks = 0
def click_button():
    global clicks
    clicks += 1
    labelClick['text'] = str(clicks)
    labelClick.pack()
    
    count = rn.randrange(1,10,1)
    print(count)
    count = str(count)
    
    if count == '1':
        bgcolor='blue'
    if count == '2':
        bgcolor='green'
    if count == '3':
        bgcolor='red'
    if count == '4':
        bgcolor='yellow'
    if count == '5':
        bgcolor='orange'
    if count == '6':
        bgcolor='brown'
    if count == '7':
        bgcolor='violet'
    if count == '8':
        bgcolor='grey'     
    if count == '9':
        bgcolor='pink'
    #bgcolor='blue'


        
    but_0 = Button(text=count, width=3, height=1, bg= bgcolor, font='Hack 30', command=click_button)
    print(bgcolor)
    but_0.place(x=310, y=140)
    
    
labelClick = Label(root, text=clicks)
labelClick.pack()



but_1 = Button(text='1', width=3, height=1, bg='blue', font='Hack 30', command=click_button)
but_2 = Button(text='2', width=3, height=1, bg='green', font='Hack 30', command=click_button)
but_3 = Button(text='3', width=3, height=1, bg='red', font='Hack 30', command=click_button)
but_4 = Button(text='4', width=3, height=1, bg='yellow', font='Hack 30', command=click_button)
but_5 = Button(text='5', width=3, height=1, bg='orange', font='Hack 30', command=click_button)
but_6 = Button(text='6', width=3, height=1, bg='brown', font='Hack 30', command=click_button)
but_7 = Button(text='7', width=3, height=1, bg='violet', font='Hack 30', command=click_button)
but_8 = Button(text='8', width=3, height=1, bg='grey', font='Hack 30', command=click_button)
but_9 = Button(text='9', width=3, height=1, bg='pink', font='Hack 30', command=click_button)


but_1.place(x=210, y=240)
but_2.place(x=310, y=240)
but_3.place(x=410, y=240)
but_4.place(x=210, y=340)
but_5.place(x=310, y=340)
but_6.place(x=410, y=340)
but_7.place(x=210, y=440)
but_8.place(x=310, y=440)
but_9.place(x=410, y=440)
 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

во первых - не корректно спрашивать "что добавить" во вторых зачем вы добавили метки android и pygame ведь для андроид используется kivy а к пайгейм вопрос отношения не имеет, в третьих ЗАЧЕМ ПИСАТЬ ИГРУ НА tkinter`е!?